# Why do I get OSError on the Python Shell 3.6.4?

Tags: python-3.x, shell, python-idle

I tried to disable Windows firewall and yet its not rectified.

This was my simple command on the Python 3.6.4 Shell. Its from Anacoda 3.

```
>>> 1 + 2
IDLE internal error in runcode()
Traceback (most recent call last):
File "C:\Users\Arshad Shariff\Anaconda3\lib\idlelib\rpc.py", line 339, in putmessage
r, w, x = select.select([], [self.sock], [])
TypeError: argument must be an int, or have a fileno() method.

During handling of the above exception, another exception occurred:

Traceback (most recent call last):
```

Will manipulating these lines 240, 339 , 342 somehome bring the shell into working?

```
File "C:\Users\Arshad Shariff\Anaconda3\lib\idlelib\rpc.py", line 240, in asyncqueue
self.putmessage((seq, request))
File "C:\Users\Arshad Shariff\Anaconda3\lib\idlelib\rpc.py", line 342, in    putmessage
raise OSError("socket no longer exists")
OSError: socket no longer exists
```

I do not know how to solve it.

Comment: Also the Shell is being unresponsive upon running a program from Python IDLE.

Comment: I am an IDLE maintainer, and I cannot remember seeing anything like this.  I know that people have successfully run IDLE within the Anaconda distribution.  I have to wonder whether you have a bad copy of one of the files.  Can you say more about how you start IDLE?  What is printed before the first `>>>`?  Is `1+2` your first input?  Is the result repeatable?  Can you edit and save a .py file, even if does not run in Shell correctly?  Is syntax coloring working?  (Strings green, comments orange, etc, with the default color theme.  `if int('1'):` should have 4 colors.)

Comment: Hi, Terry, thank you. I start the idle from lib folder -> idlelib -> idle exe icon. Yeah it was my first input, yes i was able to edit and save a .py file using command prompt. Yep coloring was totally fine.                           Nonentheless,I reinstalled it again, Its working.

Comment: Thank you for following through on the diagnostic steps and reporting back.  I now know better what a broken file might look like.

Answer (score 0):

Since "reinstall" was the answer, I am posting it as such.